# Fetching translated allowed_values of non-translatable list_string field

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-field-api

I'm attempting to get the `allowed_values` of a non-translatable `list_string` field. The `allowed_values` of this field are translated though and we want to get those `allowed_values` **into a specific language & not the current UI one**.

Here is my draft attempt:

```
// Override language before loading field configuration.
$this->languageManager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($this->languageManager->getLanguage('fr'));

// Load the field configuration in the language forced before. 
$field_info = $this->fieldConfigStorage->load('profile.customer.field_title');
$label = $field_info->getLabel();
$allowed_values = $field_info->getSetting('allowed_values');

// Dump values for debugging.
dump($label);
dump($field_info);
dump($allowed_values);
```

With my current code, I get the proper forced `label` (here `fr`) but when I use the `::getSetting('allowed_values')` I receive the `allowed_values` in the current UI language instead of forced one.

Does any one have any idea ?
Many thanks.

Comment: Do you rely on config-translation module from core (or which one) ? How are defined *allowed_values* for that field ?

Comment: Hello Eric,

Yes indeed, we use the Core implementation of List Text Field & we use the standard configuration translation feature, you can see an example here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233320/translate-the-allowed-values-list-of-an-entity-access-field

Allowed values are defined in the field configuration (and translation also) as they should be.